# how to design circular count down timer for 30 second using SVG or JavaScript or Jquery?

Tags: jquery, svg, web, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for 30 second circular count down timer filling ring using SVG or JavaScript or Jquery. I have found below example in stackoverflow and I'm trying to implement it using function but facing problem in feeling ring using animation. I cannot start my timer again before 30 second as it shows previous ring filling. Please suggest. Working Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qZrgS/90/

**Jquery**

```
$scope.startTimer = function(){
 var time = 30;
 var initialOffset = '220';
 var i = 1
 $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-(1*(initialOffset/time)));
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
   if (i == time) {    
     clearInterval(interval);
     return;
   }
   $('.circle_animation').css('stroke-dashoffset', initialOffset-((i+1)*(initialOffset/time)));
   i++;  
   }, 1000);
  };
```

**Css**

```
svg {
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
.circle_animation {
  stroke-dasharray: 220; /* this value is the pixel circumference of the circle */
  stroke-dashoffset: 220;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

**Html**

```
<svg class="countdownTimer " width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <g>
        <circle class="circle" cx="41" cy="41" r="37" stroke-width="1" fill="none" stroke="grey"/>
        <circle ng-init="startTimer();" id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="34.44" cy="41" cx="41" stroke-width="5" stroke="#0288d1" fill="none"/><circle class="circle" cx="41" cy="41" r="32" stroke-width="1" fill="none" stroke="grey"/><span ng-init="timer();RequestSend();"  id="countdowntimer" class="timeNumber">30</span>
     </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the tansition use jquery animate:

```
    var startTimer = function() {
  $('.circle_animation').css({'stroke-dashoffset': 220 });
   $('.circle_animation').stop();
    var time = 30;
    var initialOffset = '0';
    var i = 1;
    $('.circle_animation').animate({'stroke-dashoffset': initialOffset },30000);

  };
```

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/qZrgS/92/

Comment: I have tried above solution and getting and error of undefined internal

Comment: I apologies for typing mistake i.e interval. My console is showing values of i which means my animation is still going on. My objective is to start animation from starting point if i close my previous animation before 30 second.

Comment: you are currently animating all the properties of circular countdown, that means even the resetting of your countdown, you will need to somehow remove the animation either by using a class, or be clearing/appending  the css animation

Comment: I tried to append the animation by setting Svg attribute. but when I recall my function previous attribute get disappeared. Please check this working jsfiddle and update it will help you http://jsfiddle.net/qZrgS/90/

Comment: this jsfiddle is not like my answer you need to initiate the interval variable outside the function

Comment: if possible can you please provide working fiddle for it. It will help me out for solution. Thank you so much Sir.